# What event should be used for checking when a user's custom status updates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, replit

I'm trying to make a vanity bot for Discord, but I'm not sure if I'm using the correct event. Here is my code:

```
client.on("presenceUpdate", newPresence => {
    let vanityRole = newPresence.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === "940679835456536596");
  const activity = newPresence.member.user.presence.activities[0].state
  if (activity === null) return;
  if (activity.includes("gg/pm")) {
    let memberTarget = newPresence.guild.members.cache.get(newPresence.member.id);
    memberTarget.roles.add(vanityRole);
    const vanity = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor(color)
      .setDescription(`<@${memberTarget.id}>, thanks for putting us in your status <3`);
      message.channel.send(vanity)
  }
  else return;
});
```

Here is the error I'm receiving:
On this line: `const activity = newPresence.member.user.presence.activities[0].state`
Error: `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined]`
`repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 1`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of your items at `newPresence.member.user.presence.activities` is equal to an empty `array` or `undefined`, therefore `newPresence.member.user.presence.activities[0] === undefined`.

You can try: `const activity = newPresence.member.user.presence.activities[0]?.state`

> The optional chaining operator (?.) enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

Comment: It says `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'` when I try this.

Comment: try `const activity = newPresence.member.user.presence?.activities[0]?.state`
Also are you guaranteed to get an `object` or `undefined` in `activities[0]` or could it possibly have another value eg `string` or `number` in there?

Comment: Still has the unexpected token error, but at the `.?` after presence. And I'm not sure, I'd have to check the docs.